# Is a license required to use the Bing maps version that's on Facebook pages?

Tags: bing-maps

I  notice that Facebook pages allow a map box that clicks to a full page, dynamic Bing map: [image]

And by just changing the address and name parameters in the link HTML I can get the map to show any location and map sign I want.

Do I need a license to generate these links myself for clients that I build a web page for?

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create links to Bing Maps that open a map to specific location using nothing more than a URL then you can do this using the documented method found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx Don't reverse engineer the maps on Facebook.

A license is not required to do this. However you will find that you are limited to only the functionality that is exposed through the URL and won't be able to do much in terms of customizations. You will also be taking users away from there current environment to the Bing Maps website which might not be the ideal user experience. If you need more customization functionality or a better user experience then you would use the Bing Maps development API and which does have some free terms of use, but also has options for licensing high volume or internal apps.

Comment: One more thing, if I could.  Does the little rectangular map that you click (see above image) fall out of the URL use we're talking about here?  On the Facebook page, the <img> tag for it has a very long src: <img class="img" alt="" src="https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDtSWwzUgHDHVlp&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Ffb . . . 0.85%26c%3D37.767009%252C-120.85004&amp;jq=100">  Is there a way to get that image once you build the URL?    I didn't see this answered in the info at the link you provided.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you want a static map image you will have to use the Bing Maps REST imagery service. This will require a Bing Maps key to access and a Bing Maps license depending on the situation. You can find documentation on this service here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701721.aspx You can also find tool to figure out if you need a license or not here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/Licensing/licensing.aspx